# How to find a distance between two node map<Integer,List<Integer>>

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, solution

I am trying to make a program to find the distance between two nodes, given parent to child relation

**Input**

```
1 2

1 3

3 4

3 5
```

I have used following  code to get the values. The tree is bidirectional and has unit distance from each node.

**Code**

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjacencies = new HashMap<Integer,  List<Integer>>(); 
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
           List<Integer> l1= new ArrayList<Integer>();
           adjacencies.put(i,l1);
        }  
        for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
            int u = in.nextInt();
            int v = in.nextInt();
            adjacencies.get(u).add(v);
            adjacencies.get(v).add(u);
        }
```

Comment: If you have a tree I'd use a tree datastructure for tree operations. Makes thinks easier to understand and code. You could use a map to directly access tree nodes by their id though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BFS to find the distance between two nodes. I hope this solution will help you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverFlow {
static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjacencies = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>(); 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
       List<Integer> l1= new ArrayList<Integer>();
       adjacencies.put(i,l1);
    }  
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        int u = in.nextInt();
        int v = in.nextInt();
        adjacencies.get(u).add(v);
        adjacencies.get(v).add(u);
    }

    findingDistanceBetweenTwoNodes(1, 3);
}
static int [] parent = new int[100];
static boolean [] visited = new boolean[100];

public static void findingDistanceBetweenTwoNodes(int nodea, int nodeb){

    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    q.add(nodea);
    parent[nodea] = -1;
    visited[nodea] = true;
    boolean loop = true;
    while(!q.isEmpty() && loop){
        int element = q.remove();
        Integer s =null;

        while((s = getChild(element))!=null) {
            parent[s] = element;
            visited[s] = true;
            if(s == nodeb)
            {
                loop= false;
                break;
            }

            q.add(s);
        }
    }
    int x = nodeb;
    int d = 0;
    if(!loop)
     {
        while(parent[x] != -1)

     {
         d +=1;
         x = parent[x];
     }

    System.out.println("\nThe distance from node "+nodea+ " to node "+nodeb+" is "   +d);
     }
    else
        System.out.println("Can't reach node "+nodeb);
}


private static Integer getChild(int element) {
    ArrayList<Integer> childs = (ArrayList<Integer>) adjacencies.get(element);
    for (int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++) {
        if(!visited[childs.get(i)])
        return childs.get(i);
    }
    return null;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assume that one node can have only one parent node.

create a `TreeNode` type, it can have `TreeNode parent, List<TreeNode> children` attributes. The root node `parent` is null, leaf nodes have no `children`

I think this tree structure makes your work easier.

Answer (score 0):

Although not impossible, personally I think that navigating a Map as a representation of a tree is too cumbersome, the best would be a data structure as described in previous answer - one where the object has its parent and children.

Calculating a distance between them is than a question of traversing the tree while looking for certain nodes, if you have no knowledge of tree traversal you can start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal, but it's nothing difficult, there are just more ways to go through it.

Comment: is there a way to find height for the above map  implementation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do it with a simple DFS procedure since it's easier to code and doesn't require extra memory (beyond recursion stack), as long as the time complexity is acceptable:

```
int dfs(int u, int pu, int target, int h, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjacencies) {
    if (u == target) { // if target reached
      return h; // return current distance
    }
    for (int v : adjacencies.get(u)) {
      if (v != pu) { // don't go up in the tree, only down
        int d = dfs(v, u, target, h+1, adjacencies);
        if (d != -1) { // if target is in this subtree
          return d;
        }
      }
    }
    return -1; // target is not in this subtree
  }
```

You can use it like:

```
int from = 1;
int to = 5;
int dist = dfs(from, -1, to, 0, adjacencies); // use from as root of DFS
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: please check your twitter account.

Comment: please reply to my mail